# Sun's movement around the Milky way and Mass extinctions

Tags: homework-and-exercises

My question is about, if it is possible that the mass extinction of Dinosaurs on Earth is caused by sun's movement around the Milky Way (instead of asteroids) where it entered into a hazardous path that had devastated effects on Earth? Does it mean we are lucky enough to be in a safe path at present and don't know what happens to future generations.

Comment: what is the actual proposed mechanism of extinction

Comment: Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358697/that-the-suns-wobble-causes-gamma-radiation-blast-onto-our-sun-and-earth/

Answer (score 2):

If I rephrase your question as “Does the Earth’s motion around and/or through the Galaxy cause periodic extinction events?”, the answer is “we don’t know, but people are working on the possibility”.

There’s a 1983 Nature paper “Periodic mass extinctions and the Sun's oscillation about the galactic plane” by Schwartz et al whose abstract provides a nice summary of the first attempts:

> Raup and Sepkoski1 have recently reported evidence fora 26-Myr periodicity in the occurrence of mass extinctions based on a study of marine fossils. The data baseline of 250 Myr suggests events of variable amplitude, with some of the strongest peaks associated with boundaries between major geological periods which have been defined by previous palaeontological studies. In a more limited quantitative study, Fischer and Arthur2 earlier cited evidence for a 32-Myr period of major extinction events. Hatfield and Camp3 were among the first to suggest that mass extinctions might be correlated with periodic galactic phenomena, noting intervals of 80–90 Myr between major mass extinctions with an exceptionally strong mass extinction every 225–275 Myr. Here we point out a possible correlation between the 26-Myr extinction period and the Sun's oscillation about the galactic plane.

Perhaps the most import work on this is by the two teams of Rhode & Muller and  Medvedev & Melott, who together have matched observations with what may be a cause. There’s a [popular article](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2007/07/30/galactic-drift-and-mass-extinction/) that covers it nicely. In summary:

> The Solar System moves up and down as it orbits the galactic core (see image at left). Mikhail Medvedev and Adrian Melott, taking that motion into account, factor in the motion of the Milky Way itself, hypothesizing that its leading, north side generates a shock wave that exposes the Earth to high-energy radiation every 64 million years or so.

More work has been done and still needs to be done, people raise concerns about the exiting evidence and struggle to get more, not everybody agrees, and in general this is a topic that seems to periodically cycle back and forth between new ideas and new evidence. 
[image]

Comment: Note that, even if this idea turns out to be true (and it doesn't really look like it at the moment), the actual extinctions are caused by perturbations of asteroids/comets. It's not a case of "instead of asteroids"